# Copy data from one csv file to another csv file using java

Tags: java, csv, filereader, filewriter, opencsv

I'm working on a Java code to copy the data from one  csv file into another csv file .

The requirement is that files (multiple files) that are uploaded in a particular path has to be copied one at a time into another csv file(say tag.csv) in a different location.Later tag.csv will be picked up by a shell script and connect to Oracle DB to run a stored procedure .All of this is done repeatedly until all the uploaded files is processed and shell script is triggered for each file separately.

Now I'm in stuck in copying the csv data .
I have tried using buffered reader,filewriter etc. but i'm unable to copy the data to tag.csv,but I could just read them .

Since Im new to java im finding it hard to understand where im going wrong.
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then feel free to edit your post :)
I can also recommend mKyong's articles for [read](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) and [write](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/), there are more approaches

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply use the Java 7 NIO2:**
**Eg:**
If you want to copy a file from one location to another, simply call:

```
Files.copy(fromPath, toPath);
```

If you want to move:

```
Files.move(fromPath, toPath);
```

With Java 7 features, you don't need to write hard code for files handling. 
Hope it help.

[Java 7 NIO2 Tutorial Link](http://www.baeldung.com/java-nio-2-file-api)

**Edited:**
But your requirement is not file copy but you want to write uploaded file contents to existing file, you can also simply use the Java 7 NIO2 features. 
**Eg:**

```
private static void writeFileAsAppend() throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = readFileAsSequencesOfLines();
        Path path = getWriteFilePath();         
        Files.write(path, lines, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}

private static List<String> readFileAsSequencesOfLines() throws IOException {
        Path path = getReadFilePath();          
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);    
        return lines;
}

private static Path getReadFilePath() {
        Path path = Paths
                .get(".\\ReadMe.csv");    
        return path.normalize();
}

private static Path getWriteFilePath() {
        Path path = Paths
                .get(".\\WriteMe.csv");    
        return path;
}
```

Comment: Sounds great. Please consider for correct answer if you satisfied with that.